# Do scientific journals accept non-specialized research?

Tags: journals, independent-researcher, publishability

I have a new idea in physics and I used simple equations that I learned in high school and YouTube. Can journals accept scientific research with clear information and its owner is not a specialist in the field of theoretical physics such as dr

Comment: Please think carefully about the importance of your work. If it is non-specialised and not described mathematically then I'm afraid it will not be taken seriously by the community (or by any journal).

Comment: This question may be of use to you: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f, particularly the answer by Kaveh.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate what you mean by “non-specialised research” or “research for non-specialists” respectively? Do you perhaps mean something like that all the physics it’s based on is taught on the undergraduate level?

Comment: I think  "research by a non-specialist"  what was meant in the title.  In which case this is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advice for getting a paper published as a highschooler](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159167/advice-for-getting-a-paper-published-as-a-highschooler)

Answer (score 8):

If your work is truly "very important and new" then any reputable physics journal will consider it. If it also uses only elementary methods in the proof then it will be especially interesting. Who you are matters not at all in such things. It is what you write and how convincing you are.

But two caveats. There are predatory journals that will publish poor work and take your money to do so. Their business model is based on preying on amateurs.

Second, it is unlikely, though not impossible, that your work is a breakthrough doesn't make some fundamental errors, precisely because you aren't a specialist and are in a poor position to judge your own work. Not impossible, but very rare that the work would stand up to scrutiny. And it needs to be the scrutiny of specialists that you need to stand up to.

I suggest that you get someone you know who can give you some advice on this. A physics professor, for example. If you can convince them that you are "on to" something, then you can submit your work to any reputable journal and see what the experts (reviewers) have to say about it.

But, don't deal with charlatans who live on payments from "non-specialists".